# Creating a character array with `new` generates more characters than I specify. C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

So I have an assignment for my CS class that's giving me some trouble. The goal is to create my own non-NULL-terminated String class without using any of the `cstring` functions. The data in the class must contain the Length of the string, a `char*` called "data", and some other things that aren't related to my question.

So when I go to allocate memory for the string, I call the `MyStrCopy(MyString* tar, const char* str)` function which uses `tar->data = new char[length]` to allocate the memory, "length" being the length of the cstring passed in as `str`, which works as intended. When allocating the memory this way, though, the array is always much larger than I specified (ex. I ask for 6 bytes and I get upwards of 11) and the number of bytes I get seems to be random and it differs per run. I tried writing a function to cull the unwanted characters, but I think I just lack the skill/knowledge as to how I would accomplish that.

This extra data has thrown a couple of my functions off-kilter and I'm stuck as to how to fix it. Any ideas?

I've defined my Class below

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#pragma once

class MyString {
private:
    char* data;
    int length;
    static bool printAsUppercase;

    int getLengnth(const char* str);
    void MyStrCopy(MyString* tar, const char* str);

public:
// Constructors
    MyString();
    MyString(const char* data);
    MyString(MyString& data2Copy);
    ~MyString();

// Operator Overloads
    // Assignment Operator
    MyString operator=(const MyString& data);
    MyString operator=(const char* data);
    // Arithmetic Operators 
    MyString operator+(const MyString& rightStr);
    // Pre/Post decrement
    MyString operator--();
    MyString operator--(int);
    // Boolean Operators
    friend bool operator==(const MyString& leftStr, const MyString& rightStr);
    friend bool operator>(const MyString& leftStr, const MyString& rightStr);
    friend bool operator<(const MyString& leftStr, const MyString& rightStr);
    // Streaming Operators
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const MyString& str);
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::ostream& is, MyString& str);
// Mutators
    MyString& uppercase();
    void cull();
// Accessors
    int getLengnth();
};
```

and here's the implementation. Note: most of this does not currently work as intended.

```cpp
#include "MyString.h"

// Constructors
MyString::MyString() {
    data = NULL;
    length = 0;
}

MyString::MyString(const char* data) {
    MyStrCopy(this, data);
}

MyString::MyString(MyString& data2Copy) {
    MyStrCopy(this, data2Copy.data);
}

MyString::~MyString() {
    delete[] data;
}

MyString MyString::operator=(const MyString& data) {
    MyString temp;
    MyStrCopy(&temp, data.data);
    return temp;
}

MyString MyString::operator=(const char* data) {
    MyString temp;
    MyStrCopy(&temp, data);
    return temp;
}

void MyString::MyStrCopy(MyString* tar, const char* str) {
    // WIP Something's not right with the NEW line
    tar->length = getLengnth(str);
    if (data != NULL)
        delete data;
    tar->data = new char[length];
    for (int i = 0; i < tar->length; i++)
        tar->data[i] = str[i];
    tar->cull();
}

void MyString::cull() {
    // WIP currently does effectively nothing
    int currLen = getLengnth(data);
    while (currLen > length)
        data[currLen--];
}

int MyString::getLengnth() {
    return length;
}

int MyString::getLengnth(const char* str) {
    int len = 0;
    while (str[len] != NULL)
        len++;
    return len;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as it turns out, the extra characters I was getting in the debugger was the debugger trying to be helpful by continuing to print characters until it found a NULL, which could have been anywhere since I wasn't allowed to Null terminate. I thought there was actually something wrong with my computer, but no it was Just the debugger. Thanks for all of the additional input on this; it really helped me figure some stuff out!

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean to do:

```
new char[tar->length];
```

The `length` property is not initialized so you get undefined behaviour, though I'd step through in a debugger to be sure. This is some confused code since `MyStrCopy` is a non-`static` function you shouldn't have to call it with an explicit `tar` argument, that's implied as `this`.

It'd make more sense to call this function `copy(const char* data)` instead of the misleading, class-name style `MyStrCopy`. Pass through only what you need to, like `data`, and work with properties directly, not indirectly through arguments.

Remember you can define a constructor in terms of another constructor:

```
MyString(const char* data);
MyString(const MyString& src) : MyString(src.data) { };
```

Where the `copy` function disappears entirely as it's just part of that first constructor.

There's also some typos in here like `getLengnth` so be sure to double-check everything.

Answer (score 3):

```
MyString::MyString(MyString& data2Copy) {
  MyStrCopy(this, data2Copy.data);
}
```

This, basically, default-constructs a new instance of `MyString`, without initializing any of its members before calling `MyStrCopy()`. In `MyStrCopy`:

```
if (data != NULL)
    delete data;
```

Since neither `data`, nor any of the other members of the new class, were initialized -- for the reasons stated above, `data` here will be random garbage and from this point on it's all undefined behavior.